# How to change the frame for the tabBar in iOS 13?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, ios13

Currently, this code:

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.5, repeats: true) { _ in
            print(">>>>> self.tbc.tabar.frame: \(self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame); \(self.tabBarController) before")
            self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 812.0, width: 375.0, height: 83.0)
            print(">>>>> self.tbc.tabar.frame: \(self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame); \(self.tabBarController) after")
        }
```

do this

> self.tbc.tabar.frame: Optional((0.0, 729.0, 375.0, 83.0)); Optional(ApplicationViewController: 0x11600c600) before
>
> self.tbc.tabar.frame: Optional((0.0, 812.0, 375.0, 83.0)); Optional(ApplicationViewController: 0x11600c600) after
>
> self.tbc.tabar.frame: Optional((0.0, 729.0, 375.0, 83.0)); Optional(ApplicationViewController: 0x11600c600) before
>
> self.tbc.tabar.frame: Optional((0.0, 812.0, 375.0, 83.0)); Optional(ApplicationViewController: 0x11600c600) after

It works correctly for iOS 12

> self.tbc.tabar.frame: Optional((0.0, 812.0, 375.0, 83.0)); Optional(ApplicationViewController: 0x7f86e7850000) before
>
> self.tbc.tabar.frame: Optional((0.0, 812.0, 375.0, 83.0)); Optional(ApplicationViewController: 0x7f86e7850000) after

So, I can't change the tabBar frame! How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It seems, for iOS13 we should use transitions instead of frames:

```
let transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: offsetY)
tabBar.transform = transform
```

helped for me.

Frames are unuseful more.